# Get the date format of given date string C#

Tags: c#

I'm using C#.

I'm looking for a way to know the given date format
I.e if i have the following date: `2016-11-17T21:00:00.180-03:00` I'm excepted to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ffZ` and if i have the following date `2016-17-11T21:00:00.180-03:00` I'm excepted to `yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.ffZ` etc..

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: If you get `2016-01-10` would you expect `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-dd-MM`? You can't know, you'll need to narrow it down to a couple of expected/allowed formats.

Comment: This sounds not reasonable since `minute` and `second` are always can be confused.

Comment: @J.C I'm not aware of any common date format that uses `mm:HH`, `ss:mm:HH` or `HH:ss:mm`. Days and months however are often in the "wrong" order.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yep, and the bad cases such as `01/01/01 00:00:00` are not judgeable, just like you said.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer ok, and what about the 'T'HH:mm:ss.ffZ part, i can know this format?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner Try and Error / loop through a list of known formats. It all depends on your context - this doesn't look like something a user would enter manually, so there probably aren't too many variations. Where do you get it from? Why isn't the format consistent and has to be guessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the format of a date as simple as calling a method or a property of a `DateTime` object.

However, it could be useful in your case the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method, which

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match **a specified format exactly**. The method returns a value that
>   indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

So, if you do this for two or more separate formats, you could validate that your string has one of the formats you are looking for or not.

For further info regarding the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx).